Multiple IPs for NIC and connection
I wanted to assign multiple IPs to same NIC for some testing.
The remote server NIC address: 50.50.50.192
The eth0 IP address: 50.50.50.242
I added another ip address using command:  ip addr add 50.50.50.241/24 dev eth0
The idea to simulate multiple IP flows. In order to do that with setup above, I tried to use iPerf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79204094/iperf-and-ip-aliasing
I also tried using code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060492/simulate-multiple-clients-with-different-ips-to-server-socket
In both cases, on server (50.50.50.192) I see connection is made by 50.50.50.242, eth0 IP address NOT additional ip address I added (50.50.50.241).
Do I need to do something more so that connection is made using eth0 additional ip address (50.50.50.241) and not original ip address (50.50.50.242).
Note: Both local and remote are openstack VMs.
Thanks in advance!

Can you verify with tcpdump on the client? You probably have some NAT rules (maybe OpenStack built-in stuff) that interfere with this.

@grawity If I run tcpdump on client thus, tcpdump src host 50.50.50.241 where 50.50.50.241 is additional IP and run client part I don't get any output but I replace IP with 50.50.50.242 which is eth0 ip, I do get output.

Does conntrack -L on the client (or sudo cat /proc/self/net/nf_conntrack) show a line for the connection?

@grawity yes: ipv4     2 tcp      6 118 TIME_WAIT src=50.50.50.241 dst=50.50.50.192 sport=54395 dport=9999 src=50.50.50.192 dst=50.50.50.242 sport=9999 dport=54395 [ASSURED] mark=0 secctx=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 zone=0 use=2. The line after that has ip addresses from "10" prefix: ipv4     2 tcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=<gateway starting with 10.>? dst=<client ip starting with 10.> sport=51327 dport=22 src=<client ip starting with 10.> dst=<gateway starting with 10.>? sport=22 dport=51327 [ASSURED] mark=0 secctx=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 zone=0 use=2. Perhaps relevant.

The mismatching orig_src and reply_dst are definite indication of NAT rules on the system itself. Check iptables-save and nft list ruleset (whichever happens to be installed), look for "snat" or "masquerade".

Normally this is something that just works by default. That is, the only thing needed to use a different IP address is to bind() the client socket to it, which iperf already does.
So if the program binds to one local address, but tcpdump shows packets exiting with another source address, that's most likely to be an iptables or nftables NAT rule on the same system – e.g. an overly broad masquerade rule.
One way to confirm this is to check the conntrack table used by the firewall, via conntrack -L or the /proc/self/net/nf_conntrack file. It will have two sets of src/dst fields for each connection – the first pair is the original (output) addresses, then the second src/dst pair has "expected reply" (input) addresses.
If they don't match (specifically, in this case, if orig_src does not match reply_dst), then the address was rewritten by iptables NAT rules. Use iptables-save or nft list ruleset to find the rule, and narrow it down or remove if needed.
For example, if you have:
oifname eth0 masquerade

then it will unconditionally apply SNAT to all outgoing packets, rewriting them to have the interface's first IP address – even if they already come from the same interface's another address. So narrow it down by adding a "source IP address" exclusion:
ip saddr != 50.50.50.0/24 oifname eth0 masquerade

likewise -s ! 50.50.50.0/24 for iptables.

Side note in regards to the previous Stack Overflow post:
There's no such thing as IP aliasing. Addresses aren't aliased to one another; what you had before with eth0:1 is literally just multiple independent addresses on the same eth0 interface (like you have now from "ip addr add").
It's interfaces that have aliases on Linux – or rather had long ago. "Alias interfaces" were an ancient workaround for a deficient Linux API that (at the time) was used to configure network interfaces, and which had only a "set address" function but not "add/remove address", so the system had to invent fake interfaces for each new address.
But interface aliases haven't been necessary since kernel 2.4.x (~20 years ago), which introduced a more modern API which lets one simply add multiple addresses to the same interface – which you can do using 'ip addr add' nowadays – and they only stick around in 'ifconfig' because it still uses that old API.

When I run nft list ruleset I get chain nat_POST_prod-eth0_allow {                 meta nfproto ipv4 oifname != "lo" masquerade         } . If this is what you are referring to, how do edit or even regenerate the rules? The only text file which contains "oifname" on system is /etc/nftables/nat.nft. Not sure what to do with it. Sorry this is first time I am coming across nft so I am using very basic question such as one in this comment.

To be honest, the chain name "nat_POST_prod-eth0_allow" looks very much like a custom configuration set up by another admin, so you should also be talking to them about the changes before doing it. (Especially since the entire file might be auto-generated by some or other devops tooling, and your changes might disappear when the other admin re-deploys configuration...)

But if you want to change it anyway, then either a) edit the rule in "nat.nft" to add ip saddr != 50.50.50.0/24 like in the example I had (e.g. immediately before "masquerade", position doesn't matter much), or b) add a new ip saddr 50.50.50.0/24 return rule immediately above it.

After editing, first do a nft list ruleset > backup.nft Just In Case™, and finally load the new rules using either systemctl reload nftables or nft -f /etc/nftables.conf – this can vary a little between Linux distributions (well, it's usually /etc/nftables.conf, and I am guessing yours will have an "include /etc/nftables/nat.nft" or similar). I would first try to reload the systemd service if it exists, as not all Linux distros have the 'flush ruleset' within nftables.conf.
